# Conditional average with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, average

Given a 2x3 array, I want to calculate the average on `axis=0`, but only considering values that are larger than 0.

So given the array

```
[ [1,0],
  [0,0],
  [1,0] ]
```

I want the output to be

```
# 1, 0, 1 filtered for > 0 gives 1, 1, average = (1+1)/2 = 1
# 0, 0, 0 filtered for > 0 gives 0, 0, 0, average = 0    
[1 0]
```

My current code is

```
import numpy as np

frame = np.array([ [1,0],
                   [0,0],
                   [1,0] ])

weights=np.array(frame)>0

print("weights:")
print(weights)

print("average without weights:")
print((np.average(frame, axis=0)))

print("average with weights:")
print((np.average(frame, axis=0, weights=weights)))
```

This gives me

```
weights:
[[ True False]
 [False False]
 [ True False]]
average without weights:
[ 0.66666667  0.        ]
average with weights:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\myuser\project\test.py", line 123, in <module>
print((np.average(frame, axis=0, weights=weights)))
File "C:\Users\myuser\Miniconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 1140, in average
"Weights sum to zero, can't be normalized")
ZeroDivisionError: Weights sum to zero, can't be normalized
```

I don't understand this error. What am I doing wrong and how can I get the average for all values greater than zero along `axis=0`? Thanks!

Comment: `0, 0, 0 filtered for > 0 gives 0, 0, 0`... no it doesn't. Can you give a more precise description of how you want to handle the case where no positive elements are found? Should the result always be 0? Should the result be the average of all elements? Should some other value be imputed?

Comment: A weighted average is calculated as a sum of products of the averaged numbers and weights, divided by the sum of the weights. Since your weights for the second column add up to 0 (all three of them are `False`), the division is not possible.

Comment: And feedback on the posted solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the mask of greater than zeros and use it to do elementwise multilication and sum-reduction along the first axis. Finally, divide by the number of masked elements along the first axis for getting the average values.

Thus, one solution would be -

```
mask = a > 0 # Input array : a
out = np.einsum('i...,i...->...',a,mask)/mask.sum(0)
```

Sample run -

```
In [52]: a
Out[52]: 
array([[ 3, -3,  3],
       [ 2,  2,  0],
       [ 0, -3,  1],
       [ 0,  1,  1]])

In [53]: mask = a > 0

In [56]: np.einsum('i...,i...->...',a,mask) # summations of > 0s
Out[56]: array([5, 3, 5])

In [57]: np.einsum('i...,i...->...',a,mask)/mask.sum(0) # avg values of >0s
Out[57]: array([ 2.5       ,  1.5       ,  1.66666667])
```

To account for all zero columns, it seems we are expecting `0` as the result. So, we can use `np.where` to do the choosing, like so -

```
In [61]: a[:,-1] = 0

In [62]: a
Out[62]: 
array([[ 3, -3,  0],
       [ 2,  2,  0],
       [ 0, -3,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  0]])

In [63]: mask = a > 0

In [65]: np.where( mask.any(0), np.einsum('i...,i...->...',a,mask)/mask.sum(0), 0)
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
Out[65]: array([ 2.5,  1.5,  0. ])
```

Just ignore the warning there.

If you feel paranoid about warnings, use `masking` -

```
mask = a > 0
vm = mask.any(0) # valid mask
out = np.zeros(a.shape[1])
out[vm] = np.einsum('ij,ij->j',a[:,vm],mask[:,vm])/mask.sum(0)[vm]
```

Comment: Of course, you're still dividing by zero in the no-positive-elements case, so you'll get a NaN average if that happens. The underlying conceptual problem of trying to take the average of no numbers is still there.